# How to change mirror to a fast and near site for archive.raspbian.org

Tags: raspbian, apt

I am on Raspbian lite and have a slow internet connection.

I am trying to pull `lightdm` using `apt-get` but looks like it's a big deal to pull 250 MB over a slow internet connection. So I am looking for a fast mirror I can set up in my Raspbian lite installed.

Is it possible to change site to apt-get packages ?

For example I googled and found this : http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/

Looks promising but I do not know how to set it up.

Similar question on askubuntu : https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example I googled and found this : http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org

That's what you are already using; have a look in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.  Notice it is called a *mirrordirector*, meaning it redirects traffic, although I am not sure how many choices it actually has to redirect to.  Raspbian has no where near the user base or resource that Ubuntu does, so it is unrealistic to expect it the repositories are going to provide the same kind of coverage or bandwidth.

The problem, such as it is, is either where you are located or with your local network.  If you can't do anything about either of those things you will just have to be patient.

Answer (score 4):

Even though it's the accepted answer, the previous answer doesn't actually answer the question. While it's true that raspbian isn't as popular as Ubuntu, that doesn't indicate that one shouldn't believe there aren't mirrors. There are in fact plenty of mirrors and having a mirror can save you from having to wait days to successfully update your system.

You can change the source of your apt packages by editing the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` . You'll need to use sudo since the file is owned by root. So you might try the following in the terminal...

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Once you open the file you should see a line starting with `deb`. Below that is a `deb-src` line for packages to help you compile packages from source, which you can probably ignore. You may or may not currently be using mirrordirector.raspbian.org and that may or may not give you the best results. To try it change the url in the `deb` line to `http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/` . If that doesn't work well for you, then you can switch the URL with one that seems nearest to you from this list https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors .

There's another file for apt sources in recent raspbian open it with...

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
```

Then change the URL in the probably top line starting with `deb` to one of the URLs from the list linked above like `http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/archive.raspbian.org/archive/raspbian` if you are near Oxford England or `http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/` if you are in China. Then just save the file and update your repository data with...

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you are ready to go. Good Luck!

Comment: `There's another file for apt sources in recent raspbian open it with...` raspi.list contains the source for the RPF additions/modifications. There is no mirror site for that. If you change it you will get no updates, etc. for these packages (which includes kernel updates)

Comment: @Dirk could you elaborate a little? I am using a mirror presently and it seems to work great.

Comment: So you replaced `archive.raspberrypi.org` in raspi.list with something else? What does e,g, `apt policy raspberrypi-bootloader` give as output?

Comment: `~ $ apt policy raspberrypi-bootloader
    raspberrypi-bootloader:
      Installed: 1.20190215-1
      Candidate: 1.20190215-1
      Version table:
      *** 1.20190215-1 500
               500 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf Packages
              100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`